# Ubuntu 16.04 boots into emergency mode intermittently

Tags: 16.04, server

> I have a Ubuntu 16.04 based VM, it sometimes boots into Emergency
>   mode. The problem is it is not a frequent thing, once it goes into
>   emergency mode and I issue reboot command it boots back up normally,
>   but after few reboots it shows emergency mode again.
>
> Just before it boots into emergency mode I can see on the console
>   **"Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2du\some\some"**.
>
> After this
>   the message dependency failed for /data. Dependency failed for local
>   file system. Then after a few service starts. Enter root password to
>   enter Maintenance mode or press Ctrl+D to continue.
>
> This keeps happening on and off. I disabled squid service which was
>   seen starting just before the dependency message but no use. The
>   problem I am unable to find what dependency is failing. One reboot the issue > > is present the next its gone.
>
> On checking logs via **journalctl -xb**. It shows local-fs.target failed.[journatctl log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLjAe.jpg)
>
> This is the screen just before I get the prompt for emergency mode.
>   [Disk fail before boot in emergency mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYpZB.jpg)

Comment: More information needed. Please post the full output you get when it boots into emergency mode.

Comment: @daumie I have edited the post to include the screenshot after which I get a prompt for root password to enter emergency mode. Just an FYI the squid service its trying to stop and shows a countdown, I uninstalled squid after that.

Answer (score 0):

My Ubuntu had a similar problem as I'd removed an USB drive without removing the /etc/fstab entry.  Once I commented the usb drive line out and rebooted every thing was ok.  Perhaps your drive is not ready when the VM boots.  See if you can attach it after boot.